# Repeat Same Action In VB Console every second

Tags: vb.net

I want to execute this code, unfortunately it executes only once and then stops. how do execute this code to display every second? and after doing this 100 times, to stop, that is, after a fixed 100 seconds.

```
Do

    Dim index As Integer = 0

    index += 1

    Console.WriteLine(RandomString(102, 102))

    Console.ReadLine()
    Do
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Loop Until index = 100

Loop
```

Comment: You thread sleep is inside of an infinite loop. Why not simply use a timer?

Comment: You should get rid of the inner loop and move the `Until index = 100` part to the end. Oh, and you need to move the `Dim index` line above `Do`.

Comment: Look at what you are doing in the inside loop: nothing.  You are not incrementing `index`.  You are not printing anything.  `Console.ReadLine()` also waits for user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
Do Until index = 100
       index += 1

       Console.WriteLine(RandomString(102, 102))
       Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
Loop
Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Should probably also remove the `Console.ReadLine()` line as LarsTech indicated above.